# Internal and External direct products question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be the following group where A and B are subgroups of G.

$G= \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \ : \  a \in \mathbb{R} / \{0\},\  b \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace$

$A= \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \  : \ a \in \mathbb{R} / \{0\} \right\rbrace$

$B= \left\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \ : \  b \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace$

Given that A and B are abelian and that $BA=G $

Appealing to the following theorem:

Theorem: Let G be a group suppose say that H and K are subgroups of G such that $G = H x K $ (the internal direct product) then $ G \cong H \oplus K $

Explain why A,B cannot both be normal subgroups.

I dont understand why G is not isomorphic to $H \oplus K $ if i knew that to be the case i could use the following definition

Definition: let G be a group we that G is the internal direct product of two subgroups H and K if the following hold.

i) H and K are normal subgroups of G

ii) $ H \cap K = \{e\} $

iii) HK=G

Which
ii)$A \cap B =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $ so true

iii) is true by a previous part of the question. so true

implying that the definition is failing in one regard and it has to be failing in the fact that one of these subgroups is not normal (its A ).

can someone explain why G is not isomorphic to $H \oplus K$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ were a direct product of $A,B$, then $A$ and $B$ would commute, i.e., we would have $ab = ba$ for all $a \in A$, $b \in B$. But you can check that this is not the case with the matrices you have written down. In terms of affine maps, the composition $(x + b) \circ (ax) = ax +b$, whereas $(ax) \circ (x + b) = ax + ab$. Here it turns out that $G$ is a *semidirect product* of $A$ and $B$.